# EF Code First configuration- Join table dilemna

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following 2 entity relationships that I'm having a lot of trouble getting the mapping right (using fluent api)

Basically, a `User` can be both a lender and borrower of `Item` . In other words `Item` can be borrowed by multiple `User`s but can only be owned by one `User`

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsOwned { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsBorrowed{ get; set; } 
}

public class Item {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual User ItemOwner{ get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<User> ItemBorrowers { get; set; }
}
```

Looks like I need one-to-many  and also many-to-many.
I've tried countless configurations and I think I'm just confusing myself.

How do get the relationships right? Do I need a join table or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks ok on a first look (and what @Jayantha proposed should do if it's straight enough) - though normally you have one 'item' borrowed at one time (so that'd be one-to-many then also).

If you're looking for a history of 'borrowed' items (which makes its many-to-many) - then you'd need to make a hand-made index table with additional flags (like `active` etc.).

For more complex scenarios take a look at these detailed examples I made a while ago - it has most of the mappings you may need.

[Many to many (join table) relationship with the same entity with codefirst or fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041695/many-to-many-join-table-relationship-with-the-same-entity-with-codefirst-or-fl/10048992#10048992)

[Code First Fluent API and Navigation Properties in a Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154512/code-first-fluent-api-and-navigation-properties-in-a-join-table/10155439#10155439)

[EF code-first many-to-many with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199158/ef-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-data/10199455#10199455)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create mapping like this ,

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(i=>i.ItemOwner).WithMany(u=>u.ItemsOwned );          
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasMany(i=>i.ItemBorrowers ).WithMany(u=>u.ItemsBorrowed);          
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How does this differ from the many-to-many strategy I see in other examples using Map(mc => { /* MapLeftKey/MapRightKey/ToTable */ });? Am trying your answer now.

Comment: Not seems to be working for the many-to-many portion am getting Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Item_ItemBorrowers_Source' in relationship 'Item_ItemBorrowers'. Valid values for multiplicity for the Principal Role are '0..1' or '1'. Any ideas?

Comment: Ended up going with a join table as NSGaga described.