# MVC4 / EF / Code First - InvalidCastException when instantiating ICollections in a derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I'm trying to `new` ICollections in my derived classes - should this be done in the object constructor or/and when I'm creating a new instance of an object in my `Register ActionResult()`?

Tenant inherits from UserProfile - simplified example:

```
public class Tenant : UserProfile
{
    public Tenant() 
    {
        this.ReferencePhotos = new List<ReferencePhoto>();
        // ReferencePhoto extends Image
    }

    // A Tenant can have many ReferencePhotos
    [ForeignKey("ImageId")] // Id of parent class
    public virtual ICollection<ReferencePhoto> ReferencePhotos { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to do the above but it results in an InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Namespace.Models.ReferencePhoto]' to type [Namespace.Models.ReferencePhoto]'.

Why is it trying cast from one object to another when they're the same?

In my `Register ActionResult()` I've also tried this (with and without setting ICollections in object contructor):

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    using (var db = new LetLordContext())
    {
        var tenant = db.UserProfile.Create<Tenant>();
        tenant.ReferencePhotos = new List<ReferencePhoto>();
        // Do I need to new it here at all/as well?
        db.UserProfile.Add(tenant);     // Exception being thrown here
        db.SaveChanges();

        Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Tenant");

        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Home", tenant);
     } 
}
```

The above also throws the same exception mentioned earlier. Can anyone offer any insight?

**EDIT:** Added UserProfile code

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account type is required.")]
    public AccountType AccountType;

    public virtual string AccountTypeString
    {
        get { return AccountType.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            AccountType newValue;
            if (Enum.TryParse(value, out newValue))
            { AccountType = newValue; }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Added context code and ReferencePhoto code

```
public class LetLordContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }                  // 1 DbSet for superclass UserProfile
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.Image> Image { get; set; }                              // 1 DbSet for superclass Image
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.ResidentialProperty> ResidentialProperty { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.TenantGroupMember> TenantGroupMember { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.Viewing> Viewing { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.TenantPreferences> TenantPreferences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.LandlordPreferences> LandlordPreferences { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LetLord.Models.Address> Address { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

I'm using table-per-type inheritance hence only `DbSet`s for base classes are implemented.

```
public class ReferencePhoto : Image
{
    // 1:many with Tenant
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

---

I can workaround this issue by not initialising the list in the object constructor or when creating a new entity. To achieve this I use a null coalescing operator in the GET `ActionResult` that returns a `Tenant` object in a partial view. In the partial, I check if `Model.ReferencePhotos == null`. If it is, a user can upload a photo. When a photo is uploaded, it is added to the list, I can confirm this by checking the database. However, when I login again, the `if` in the partial view mentioned previously throws the following exception:

> Unable to set field/property ReferencePhotos on type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tenant_...

with an inner exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ReferencePhoto_3DFB9F64061D55E5AF6718A74C97025F77EFB2BB9C2A6E43F5A6AF62A6A73E75' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LetLord.Models.ReferencePhoto]'."}

This may provide more insight.

Comment: Can you inherit your class from ObservableCollection<ReferencePhoto>? This will make your class a list of items. So you will not need to have a list inside your class. This will not apply if you have more members in your class.

Comment: I haven't come across ObservableCollections. There are other properties and ICollections in Tenant, so going on what you've said, I don't think it would apply.

Comment: by your err it seems you're trying to cast `list` into `single instance` - I don't see that in your code - what's UserProfile also

Comment: @NSGaga please see edit; added UserProfile code. UserProfile is just a base class that represents common properties between Tenant and other classes such as Landlord.

Comment: `type [Namespace.Models.ReferencePhoto]'` - do you have a 'single photo' assignment somewhere - that err is quite specific (unless you cut it off).  And what's your fluent code, db setup.

Comment: I don't have a 'single photo' assignment. Image is extended twice to ReferencePhoto and PropertyPhoto. I'm not using any fluent code, all relations are handled by annotations. Please see edit, added more code.

Comment: @NSGaga any more ideas? Please see edit as I've added some information that may be of help.

Comment: I'm not here all the time :). Anyway, what you're having is TPH (if I'm reading your code in it's entirety), TPT needs to have `Table[]` on each or fluent code (not sure which version you have but that should be default)...

Comment: Try removing the `ForeignKey` that should be set on the `one` side (of one-to-many - sort of) - and that might as well be adding extra foreign key (as a 'single' vs collection) and making all the problems. I don't have much time now, just a tip, let me know and we'll figure this out, details.

Comment: Sorry! I'm actually using TPT, I do have each class annotated with [Table("...")], I just left it out to simplify the question - I should have put it in though. I'll try what you've suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the...

```
[ForeignKey("ImageId")] // Id of parent class
```

> ForeignKey that should be set on the 'one' side (of one-to-many - sort
>   of), never on collections - and it's only defined on the `ReferencePhoto` (via `UserId`
>   which you already have attributed).

...and **that might as well be adding extra foreign key** - and resulting in that `single instance vs collection` error.

---

Some more info on how `ForeignKey` should be defined (`ForeignKey vs InverseProperty` etc.), and some good advices from gurus :)

[Entity Framework 4.1 InverseProperty Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716528/entity-framework-4-1-inverseproperty-attribute)

[How Should I Declare Foreign Key Relationships Using Code First Entity Framework (4.1) in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542864/how-should-i-declare-foreign-key-relationships-using-code-first-entity-framework/5543702#5543702)

---

For more complex scenarios (with many-to-many and manually defining relations in fluent code - which I recommend) - take a look at these detailed examples I made a while ago - it has most of the mappings you may need.

[Many to many (join table) relationship with the same entity with codefirst or fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041695/many-to-many-join-table-relationship-with-the-same-entity-with-codefirst-or-fl/10048992#10048992)

[Code First Fluent API and Navigation Properties in a Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154512/code-first-fluent-api-and-navigation-properties-in-a-join-table/10155439#10155439)

[EF code-first many-to-many with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199158/ef-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-data/10199455#10199455)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, cheers. I can't remember if I saw in a tutorial or just did it myself - putting FK annotations on collections. I ran into one small problem with a many-to-many relationship (Tenant and Viewing) regarding what you suggested above; I dropped and recreated my database and EF gave an error "Foreign Key contraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" in relation to table TenantViewing. I used modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); to resolve the issue. I only have one association table - could this be an issue?

Comment: I just posted an edit - to add some links I made for many-to-many - has all to cover very complex cases. It's hard to say, that's a known error but can't recall just what it is that's triggering it. In my experience, it's all much easier, safer to control via fluent configuration - hence why I do it that way, there're always issues with attributes you can't entirely resolve unless you control all the fields and mappings.

Comment: you can always make, open another question with some details about it - and here we go again :) - just '@' reference me so that I know to take a look, or here